# Where on earth is the glare node?

Tags: node-editor

I've been looking for the Glare node for hours... and I can't find it. Where in the settings is it?

[image]

Comment: The glare node is not a material node but a compositing node.

Comment: @lemon wow I'm such an idiot... thanks a lot man.